# Prove that any positive integer that divides both $c-a$ and $c+a$ must be equal to 1 or 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Consider $b^2=c^2-a^2=(c-a)(c+a)$. Prove that any positive integer that divides both $c-a$ and $c+a$ must be equal to 1 or 2 . in particular this means that $GCD(\frac{c-a}{2},\frac{c+a}{2})=1$
[image]

How to prove this can any help

Comment: Do you mean that $a$ and $c$ are coprime?

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. If $a=6$ and $c=10$, then $4$ divides both $c-a$ and $c+a$.

Comment: I think the question means that the only prime factors of $c - a$ and $c + a$ is either $1$ or $2$ if we consider $1$ to be prime only for this case, since $2\mid 4$. But, if $1$ only divides $c - a$ and/or $c + a$ then both the expressions must be prime, so the proposition is invalid.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your example doesn't satisfy $c^2-a^2=b^2$

Comment: @Landuros Since there is no $b$ in my answer, I don't understand your remark.

Comment: @Landuros I've edited my answer. Now, $a$ and $c$ are such that $c^2-a^2$ is a perfect square. Do you agree with my answer now?

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos Thanks. The OP's first line was to consider $b^2=c^2-a^2$. +1